# IPython in Safari: websocket connection failure

Tags: python, safari, websocket, jupyter-notebook

Despite being listed in the [ipython-notebook doc](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/install/install.html) as one of the supported browsers, `Safari` `5.1.10` running on `OSX 10.6.8(64bit)` can not run `IPython-notebook` fully functionally. `ipython` version `2.2.0`, in `anaconda` `python` environment.

Safari displays the list of notebooks OK. Every aspects seem to be fine until one opens (or creates a new) notebook. A error message shows up:

```
"A WebSocket connection could not be established. 
 You will NOT be able to run code.
 Check your network connection or notebook server configuration."
```

Basically the cell shows up alright, but you can't run them.

`Firefox 32.0.3` can, however, fully functions with `IPython notebook`. Therefore it is not a `IPython notebook` problem. Therefore there is no error message in the terminal, `i.e`:

```
6600sls-Mac-Pro:~ bio101sl$ ipython notebook --no-browser
2014-11-11 12:23:39.339 [NotebookApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/Users/bio101sl/.ipython/profile_default'
2014-11-11 12:23:39.369 [NotebookApp] Using MathJax from CDN: https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js
2014-11-11 12:23:39.541 [NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/bio101sl/IPython_NB
2014-11-11 12:23:39.542 [NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
2014-11-11 12:23:39.542 [NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
2014-11-11 12:23:39.542 [NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

Seems to be a `Safari` - `websocket` related problem. Is there any settings in `Safari` has to be changed to get it work? Unfortunately [ipython-notebook doc](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/install/install.html) doesn't provide any hint on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out not to be a browser issue either. It has to do with the `tornado` `4.0.2` shipped with `anaconda`, which is not compatible with `Safari` `5.1.10`. Downgrade `tornado` to `3.2.2` solved the problem, in terminal:

```
conda install tornado=3.2
```

`3.2.2` appears to be the last version that will work with `Safari` `5.1.10`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem using Safari 5.1.7 on Windows. Solution: I set Chrome version 40.0.2214.115 m as default browser.